# Reading "this" and "use" arguments from a PHP closure

Tags: php, closures, php-7.1

When you create a method that returns a closure in PHP:

```
class ExampleClass {
  public function test() {
    $example = 10;

    return function() use ($example) {
      return $example;
    };
  }
}
```

The result of `print_r` contains `this` (the class whose method created the closure) and `static`, which appears to be the values bound within the `use ()` statement of the closure:

```
$instance = new ExampleClass();
$closure = $instance->test();

print_r($closure);
```

Producing:

```
Closure Object (
    [static] => Array (
        [example] => 10
    )
    [this] => ExampleClass Object()
)
```

However I cannot for the life of me work out how to capture these values. It is not possible to use any form of property accessor (e.g. `$closure->static` or `$closure->{'static'}`) without receiving the following:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Closure object cannot have properties in XYZ.

Array access notation obviously does not work either:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Closure as array in XYZ.

JSON encoding the object, besides this making the values useless were they objects, provides an empty JSON object `{}` and using the `ReflectionFunction` class does not provide access to these items.

The [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) documentation does not provide any means of accessing these values at all either.

Outside of doing something shameful like output buffering and parsing `print_r` or similar, I cannot actually see a way to get these values.

Am I missing something obvious?

> **Note:** The use-case is for implementing memoization and these values would be extremely beneficial in identifying whether or not the call matched a previous cached call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you may have overlooked some of the `ReflectionFunction` methods.

Take a look at the [`ReflectionFunction::getClosureThis()`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getclosurethis.php) method. I tracked it down by looking through the PHP 7 source code by doing a search for the [`zend_get_closure_this_ptr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getclosurethis.php) which is defined in [`zend_closures.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_closures.c).

The manual currently doesn't have a lot of documentation for this function. I'm using 7.0.9; try running this code based on your example:

```
class ExampleClass {
  private $testProperty = 33;

  public function test() {
    $example = 10;

    return function() use ($example) {
      return $example;
    };
  }
}

$instance = new ExampleClass();
$closure = $instance->test();

print_r($closure);

$func = new ReflectionFunction($closure);
print_r($func->getClosureThis());
```

You should get output similar to

```
Closure Object
(
    [static] => Array
        (
            [example] => 10
        )

    [this] => ExampleClass Object
        (
            [testProperty:ExampleClass:private] => 33
        )

)

ExampleClass Object
(
    [testProperty:ExampleClass:private] => 33
)
```

Regarding the closure static variables, these are returned with `ReflectionFunction::getStaticVariables()`:

```
php > var_dump($func->getStaticVariables());
array(1) {
  ["example"]=>
  int(10)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to get value of $example youn can try this

```
<?php
class ExampleClass {
    public function test() {
      $example = 10;

      return function() use ($example) {
        return $example;
      };
    }
}

$instance = new ExampleClass();

$number = call_user_func($instance->test(),null);
```

I found this solution into a Laravel framework and works for me.

call_user_func helps you.